# Anyway to speed up replaying blocks for nodeos?

Tags: nodeos

I understand that nodeos is a single-threaded application and having multiple cores does not do anything for it. However, I noticed that having loads of RAM help. I am running a node at 32GB of RAM and noticing hard replaying of 26M blocks taking days.

Is there any way to speed this up? Also, if the nodeos is stopped for a short time and you want to restart it, how do you make it catch up to the head block? Is that automatic or some command-line switch is needed to sync it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replaying is CPU intensive, especially single-core performance matters. Using `wabt` as web assembly runtime helps a little bit.

Regarding stopping nodeos, if you stop nodeos during replay, you will have to replay again from the very beginning. If you stop nodeos when it's already up-to-date, it will automatically start syncing again, either in batches of 1000 blocks(when the current head is in the later 1000 than local head block) or in each blocks.

Comment: could you please more elaborate on the answer? I am getting same issue